# Variable instead class in Sass mixin

Tags: css, sass

Get error: expected ':' after $selector in assignment statement

```
@mixin clip-path ($selector, $color)
  @supports (display: flex)
    $selector
      background: $color
      display: flex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need use `$selector`, just:

```
@mixin clip-path ($color)
  @supports (display: flex)
    background: $color
    display: flex
```